# How to display a message in MainActivity if there is no Internet?

Tags: java, android, xml

If there is no Internet, display a certain xml in full screen when the application starts, that there is no Internet, and if there is, perform MainActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, MaterialSearchBar.OnSearchActionListener, PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener {
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
    public static MaterialSearchBar searchBar;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private static List<String> listPermissionsNeeded;

    public boolean isInternetAvailable() {
        try {
            InetAddress address = InetAddress.getByName("www.google.com");
            return !address.equals("");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // Log error
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: setting things up");

        StaticUtils.requestQueue = (RequestQueue) Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //Admob banner
        MobileAds.initialize(this, new OnInitializationCompleteListener()  {
            @Override
            public void onInitializationComplete(InitializationStatus initializationStatus) {
            }
        });

        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        mAdView.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdLoaded() {
                super.onAdLoaded();
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

            @Override
            public void onAdFailedToLoad(int i) {
                super.onAdFailedToLoad(i);
                mAdView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }


        });
        //restoring recent searches list
        StaticUtils.recentSearchesList = getArrayList(StaticUtils.KEY_LIST_PREFERENCCES);
        if (StaticUtils.recentSearchesList==null){
            StaticUtils.recentSearchesList = new ArrayList<>();
        }
        StaticUtils.savedImagesList = new ArrayList<>();
        searchBar = findViewById(R.id.searchToolBar);
        searchBar.setHint("Search Wallpapers");
        searchBar.setOnSearchActionListener(this);
        searchBar.hideSuggestionsList();

        drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

        //sets home fragment open by default
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                new HomeFragment()).commit();

        playLogoAudio();  //to play the logo audio
        searchEvents();  //advanced search events
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        Log.d(TAG, "onBackPressed: back button invoked.");

        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public void grantPermissionBottomSheet(){
        View dialogView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.layout_bottomsheet, null);
        final BottomSheetDialog dialog = new BottomSheetDialog(this);
        Button ok = dialogView.findViewById(R.id.bt_bottomsheet);
        ok.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onClick: bottomSheet button clicked.");
                requestPermissions(MainActivity.this);
                dialog.dismiss();
            }
        });
        dialog.setContentView(dialogView);
        dialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onNavigationItemSelected: navigation item pressed.");

        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.nav_home) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_saved) {
            NetworkUtils network = new NetworkUtils(this);
            if(network.checkConnection(drawer)){   //if network connected
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_FRAG_ID,2);
                i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_SEARCH_DATA,"Saved");
                startActivity(i);
            }

        }else if (id == R.id.nav_downloads) {
            //downloaded images
            if (permissionsGranted(this)) {
                Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
                i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_FRAG_ID, 4);  //4 for downloads section
                i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_SEARCH_DATA, "Downloads");
                startActivity(i);
            }else{
                grantPermissionBottomSheet();
            }

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_share) {
            //share the app intent
            Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
            sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hey! look what I found from play store.\nDownload cool & amazing wallpapers for your device from this app, "+getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)+", among various categories.\n\nCheck this out:\n"+StaticUtils.playStoreUrlDefault+getPackageName()+"\nDownload now:)");
            sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share app through..."));

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_rate) {
            //rate the app intent
            Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName());
            Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
            // To count with Play market backstack, After pressing back button,
            // to taken back to our application, we need to add following flags to intent.
            goToMarket.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_DOCUMENT |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK);
            try {
                startActivity(goToMarket);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                        Uri.parse("http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getApplicationContext().getPackageName())));
            }

        } else if (id == R.id.nav_about) {
            //about page
            Intent i = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_FRAG_ID,3);  //3 for about fragment
            i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_SEARCH_DATA,"About");
            startActivity(i);
        }
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return true;
    }
    public void playLogoAudio(){
        Log.d(TAG, "playLogoAudio: playing logo audio");

        View headerView = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        ImageView drawerLogo = headerView.findViewById(R.id.imageLogo);
        drawerLogo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this,R.raw.hello);
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchStateChanged(boolean enabled) {
        if (enabled){
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new SearchFragment()).commit();
        }else{
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                    new HomeFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSearchConfirmed(CharSequence text) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onSearchConfirmed: confirmed search: "+text);

        Intent i = new Intent(this,SecondActivity.class);
        i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_FRAG_ID,1);
        i.putExtra(StaticUtils.KEY_SEARCH_DATA,String.valueOf(text));

        if(new NetworkUtils(getApplicationContext()).checkConnection(drawer)) {  //start intent if network connected
            StaticUtils.recentSearchesList.add(String.valueOf(text));  //adds the query to the recents list

            if (StaticUtils.recentSearchesList.size()>20){
                StaticUtils.recentSearchesList.remove(0);
            }
            SearchFragment.updateAdapter(this,StaticUtils.recentSearchesList);
            searchBar.setText("");  //removes the search query
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onButtonClicked(int buttonCode) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onButtonClicked: search interface button clicked: "+buttonCode);
        switch (buttonCode){
            case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_NAVIGATION:
                drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
                break;
            case MaterialSearchBar.BUTTON_BACK:
                searchBar.disableSearch();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPointerCaptureChanged(boolean hasCapture) {}

    public void saveArrayList(ArrayList<String> list, String key){
        Log.d(TAG, "saveArrayList: saving recent searchList data");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = gson.toJson(list);
        editor.putString(key, json);
        editor.apply();
    }

    public ArrayList<String> getArrayList(String key){
        Log.d(TAG, "getArrayList: getting saved recent searchList data");
        SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String json = prefs.getString(key, null);
        Type type = new TypeToken<ArrayList<String>>() {}.getType();

        return gson.fromJson(json, type);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //Saving arraylist when activity gets paused
        saveArrayList(StaticUtils.recentSearchesList,StaticUtils.KEY_LIST_PREFERENCCES);
    }

    public void searchEvents(){
        Log.d(TAG, "searchEvents: managing the search events");
        searchBar.addTextChangeListener(new TextWatcher() {
            ArrayList<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>();
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
                Log.d(TAG, "beforeTextChanged: clearing the list");
                if (!tempList.isEmpty()){
                    tempList.clear();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onTextChanged: changing search query");
                for (String string : StaticUtils.recentSearchesList) {
                    if (s.length() > 0) {
                        if (string.matches("(?i)(" + s + ").*")) {
                            tempList.add(string);
                            SearchFragment.updateAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tempList);
                        }
                    }else{
                        SearchFragment.updateAdapter(getApplicationContext(), StaticUtils.recentSearchesList);
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        navigationView.setCheckedItem(R.id.nav_home);
        if (!permissionsGranted(this)){   //checking and requesting permissions
            grantPermissionBottomSheet();
        }
    }

    public static boolean permissionsGranted(Context context) {
        Log.d(TAG, "checkPermissions: checking if permissions granted.");
        int result;
        listPermissionsNeeded = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String p:permissions) {
            result = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(context,p);
            if (result != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                listPermissionsNeeded.add(p);
            }
        }
        //if all/some permissions not granted
        return listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty();
    }

    public static void requestPermissions(Activity activity){
        Log.d(TAG, "requestPermissions: requesting permissions.");
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new
                String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]), StaticUtils.MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onRequestPermissionsResult: action when permission granted or denied");
        if (requestCode == StaticUtils.MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS) {
            if (grantResults.length <= 0) {
                // no permissions granted.
                showPermissionDialog();
            }
        }
    }

    public void showPermissionDialog(){
        Log.d(TAG, "showPermissionDialog: requesting permissions");

        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("Are you sure?");
        builder.setMessage("You'll not be able to use this app properly without these permissions.");
        builder.setPositiveButton("Try Again", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                //re-requesting permissions
                requestPermissions(MainActivity.this);
            }
        });
        builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
        builder.show();
    }





}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest some kind of different flow.
Most apps have something called a "Splash screen" (usually with a logo, sometimes kind of a progress bar).

what you can do is create a splash activity, - if there is internet call your MainActiviy, otherwise call another activity NetworkErrorActivity with the XML you want.

Comment: there is SplashActivity.java, only I don’t know how to do there

Comment: make your splash activity your launch activity in the manifest.
in the onResume of you splashActivity create a function to check the internet connection, if it 's working create an intent of your mainActivity and start it, if there is no internet connection create your NoInternetActivty intent and start it.